# React Class State Managment

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have a class in my react project, which I have added to a context exposing its value to all other child components. The problem I am facing is when the class value updates, none of the consumers re-render. How can I go about with this design in a way which will re-render componenets when the object is updated?

```
class User {
    constructor() {
        this.metadata = new Map<string, string>();
    }

    getFirstName = () => {
        return this.metadata.get("name");
    }
}

const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
const UserUpdateContext = React.createContext(null);

export default UserProvider( {children} ) {
    const [user, setUser] = React.useState(new User());

    return (
        <UserContext value={user}>
            <UserUpdateContext value={setUser}>
                { children }
            </UserUpdateContext>
        </UserContext>
    )
}
```

When I read in the user elsewhere in the app and update the metadata via user.metadata.set("id", 3)... this does not retrigger a re-render for all consumers. What is the way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

React and OOP don't mix well at all. The components likely aren't rerendering because you are mutating the `user` state instead of creating a new `user` state reference when you want to update part of it.

Example, ***really*** don't do this though:

```
class User {
  constructor(init = []) {
    this.metadata = new Map<string, string>(init);
  }

  getFirstName = () => {
    return this.metadata.get("name");
  }
}

const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
const UserUpdateContext = React.createContext(null);

export default UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState(new User());

  const setUserKeyValue = (key, value) => {
    const nextUser = new User(user); // <-- create new reference, copy internal state
    nextUser.metadata.set("id", 3);  // <-- update property
    setUser(nextUser);               // <-- update state
  };

  return (
    <UserContext value={user}>
      <UserUpdateContext value={setUserKeyValue}>
        {children}
      </UserUpdateContext>
    </UserContext>
  );
}
```

To effect state updates consumers should access the `UserUpdateContext` context value and invoke the `setUserKeyValue` function, passing a key and value they want to set. Consumers ***should not*** call directly the member functions of the `user` provided via the `UserContext` context.

```js
const setUserKeyValue = useContext(UserUpdateContext);

...

setUserKeyValue("id", 3);

...
```

## Suggested Solution

The React way would be to just store the user state directly:

```
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);
const UserUpdateContext = React.createContext(null);

export default UserProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({});

  const setUserKeyValue = (key, value) => {
    setUser(user => ({
      ...user,
      [key]: value,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <UserContext value={user}>
      <UserUpdateContext value={setUserKeyValue}>
        {children}
      </UserUpdateContext>
    </UserContext>
  );
}
```

```js
const setUserKeyValue = useContext(UserUpdateContext);

...

setUserKeyValue("id", 3);

...
```

```js
const user = useContext(UserContext);

...

user.name;

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one help you.

```
const updateUserMetadata = (key, value) => {
  const updatedUser = { ...user };
  updatedUser.metadata.set(key, value);
  setUser(updatedUser);
};
```